# Can't handle large integers in Python 3

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to implement a very simple RSA algorithm, when I choose 2 primes larger than 3 digits and when I try to decrypt the message my IDE freezes and I thought because of it being a bigInt so I've waited for like 10 min and nothing did happen.

Here's my code:

```
def gcd (m,n):
if (m%n ==0):
    return n
else:
    return gcd(n,m%n)

def extended_gcd(aa, bb):
    lastremainder, remainder = abs(aa), abs(bb)
    x, lastx, y, lasty = 0, 1, 1, 0
    while remainder:
          lastremainder, (quotient, remainder) = remainder,      divmod(lastremainder, remainder)
    x, lastx = lastx - quotient*x, x
    y, lasty = lasty - quotient*y, y
return lastremainder, lastx * (-1 if aa < 0 else 1), lasty * (-1 if bb < 0 else 1)

def modinv(a, m):
g, x, y = extended_gcd(a, m)
if g != 1:
    raise ValueError
return x % m
p = 9883
q = 9887
n = p*q
phi = (p-1)*(q-1)
e = 509

    m = 320

    d = modinv(e,phi)
    c = (pow(m,e)%n) 
    msg = pow(c,d) % n ## MY IDE FREEZES WHEN IT REACHES THIS LINE! SURE OF IT
    print(msg)
```

Comment: Function calls in python are expensive,  a new stack frame is created for each function and pushed onto the stack. Doing recursive methods is very inefficient using the CPython interpreter, consider using PyPy to execute this and you will see massive performance benefits(due to JIT optimizations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line :

```
c = (pow(m,e)%n)
```

should be :

```
c = (pow(m,e,n))
```

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow), this is a much more efficient approach to computing modulo over a large number

EDIT : same thing goes for :

```
msg = pow(c,d) % n
```

Which becomes :

```
msg = pow(c,d, n)
```

Regarding the size, Python is actually very smart with integers, and will switch the internal representation if a number become too big to fit in a traditional integer. Thus size is often not a concern

Comment: WOW! that was the problem! Thanks a million Mr. Rossi!